# Filtering products by multiple sizes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently building an app using a PHP CRUD API that returns objects - and in-turn used angularJS as my framework of choice.

I am having a little trouble coming up with the best way of filtering a product that has multiple sizes, but filtering a single attribute has not been an issue.

I have the sizes on a separate MySQL table and foreign key them to a unique id to join them together to the product, here is a sample of what the API returns that I am trying to filter on :

```
 "id":"1",
         "affiliate_id":"3443739433",
         "product_sku":"3443739433",
         "sizes":[  
            {  
               "id":"1076",
               "affiliate_id_options":"3443739433",
               "size":"10"
            },
            {  
               "id":"1077",
               "affiliate_id_options":"3443739433",
               "size":"12"
            },
            {  
               "id":"1078",
               "affiliate_id_options":"3443739433",
               "size":"14"
            },
            {  
               "id":"1079",
               "affiliate_id_options":"3443739433",
               "size":"16"
            },
            {  
               "id":"1080",
               "affiliate_id_options":"3443739433",
               "size":"18"
            },
            {  
               "id":"1081",
               "affiliate_id_options":"3443739433",
               "size":"20"
            }
         ],
         "product_name":"Product name 1",         
         "product_colours":"Red",
```

Following that, this is the check I am trying to do to count the unique size values, but i am having trouble iterating 'sizes'

```
    //'size' needs to check size.sizes
    $scope.sizeGroup = uniqueItems($scope.products, 'size');
    var filterAfterSizes = [];        
    $scope.selected = false;
    for (var j in $scope.products) {
        var p = $scope.products[j];
        for (var i in $scope.useSizes) {
            if ($scope.useSizes[i]) {
                $scope.selected = true;
                //needs to push the product into the new array by size
                if (i == p.sizes) {
                    filterAfterSizes.push(p);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }     
    }
```

jsfiddle of my prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/zgdd4ozv/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your fiddle:

#### 1. You have nested lists, but your `uniqueItems` function deals with flat lists only.

In order to solve this, you have two possibilities:

a. Create a helper function (e.g. `uniqueSizes`) from which you will call the `uniqueItems` function for each `products.sizes` list from your products array. This will be a highly customized solution for your current data structure. But in case your data structure will change, you'll have to adjust your function.

b. Change your `uniqueItems` function to deal with nested representations (lists as well as objects). Thus whenever your data structure will change, you'll have to just provide the path to the data values.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdmbgfcz/1/) is a fork of your fiddle with the generic `uniqueItems` function that can deal with nested lists and objects. In order to extract unique items from a nested object, provide the following string as the key parameter: `path.to.your.values`, where each word is a property on the nested object.

In case you have a nested list, provide the key using a `prop[]` form. For instance, in order to get the unique items for sizes, you make the following call: `uniqueItems($scope.products, 'sizes[].size')`

The `sizes[]` part tells that the value of the `sizes` property is an array, so the function gets to the sizes array and recursively calls itself with the sizes array as the `data` argument.

#### 2. You filter after sizes based on a flat list of objects

In your controller, you make the `if (i == p.sizes)` checking, thus comparing an actual size `i` with the whole `sizes` array of a product. You could change your filtering after sizes like so:

```
$scope.products.forEach(function(product) {
  for (var i in $scope.useSizes) {
    if ($scope.useSizes[i]) {
      $scope.selected = true;
      product.sizes.forEach(function (s) {
        if (i == s.size) {
          filterAfterSizes.push(product);
        }
      });
    }
  }     
});
```

In the fiddle from above there is this function as well and you can check how it works.

#### 3. Your counter of number of occurrences of a specific product is broken

It doesn't count correctly the products in the Size side menu. I would suggest to create an [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) to filter based on the nested structure of your sizes. Note that in that fiddle from above the count of number of occurences (the `<span class="filterCount">({{(filteredProducts | filter:size).length}})</span>` code) is not working correctly, although if you'll check a specific size, the products will be filtered out correctly.

And that's it. Good luck!

Comment: iulian, this is perfect! I agree with the counter - it looses the plot with the numbers it brings back after selecting a checkbox - if i could buy you a beer, I would! Many thanks for putting your time into this response.

Comment: i'm glad it helped you. I actually prefer tea to beer :) but you could just upvote the answer in case you feel it is useful so that others will find it helpful too ;)